# Python error unpickling set of datetime objects

Tags: python, subprocess, pickle

I am having issues unpickling objects from a subprocess (python2) that contains sets of datetime objects.  The main process is in python3.

A quick sample is:

mysubprocess.py

```
import pickle
import sys
import datetime

def testing():
    a = set([datetime.date(2020, 2, 5), datetime.date(2020, 2, 4), datetime.date(2020, 2, 3)])
    b = set([])

    mytuple = (a, b)
    sys.stdout.write(pickle.dumps(mytuple))

testing()
```

main.py

```
import subprocess
import pickle
import datetime

proc = subprocess.Popen(["python2", "mysubprocess.py"],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

output, err = proc.communicate()

if err:
    raise Exception(str(err))

a, b = pickle.loads(output)

print(a)
print(b)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    a, b = pickle.loads(output)
  File "/pypy3.6-v7.3.2-linux64/lib-python/3/pickle.py", line 1578, in _loads
    encoding=encoding, errors=errors).load()
  File "/pypy3.6-v7.3.2-linux64/lib-python/3/pickle.py", line 1070, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/pypy3.6-v7.3.2-linux64/lib-python/3/pickle.py", line 1195, in load_string
    self.append(self._decode_string(codecs.escape_decode(data)[0]))
  File "/pypy3.6-v7.3.2-linux64/lib-python/3/pickle.py", line 1186, in _decode_string
    return value.decode(self.encoding, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Try passing `encoding="utf8"` to pickle.loads (can be utf-8, too)

Comment: That doesnt work either.  But encoding with 'latin1' or 'bytes' actually works.  Apparently pickling datetime object with python2 is broken

Comment: No, the pickle file is somehow decoded with a different coding than it was encoded. But if it works with `latin1`, just use that !